# How far it is good to use HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert as caching?

Tags: c#, caching

I am going to use `HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert`  caching for my small project , it is good to use? or is there any best approach for client data caching? please help.

Answer (score 2):

It's great to use, especially on small projects. Just keep in mind that by default the cached objects are held in the worker process so will be rebuilt on any restarts, will take server memory and will have multiple copies in a web garden setup. For small projects, none of these are real issues though and HttpContext caching is simple to setup and use.